Converting numbers to their locales are not working for few locales using icu4j jar
When trying to convert english number to Japanese or thai number, iam getting english number.
I have been using latest icu4j version. When trying to convert english number to Japanese or thai number, iam getting english number.
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("123.22");
Locale locale = new Locale("th"); //Thai
NumberFormat dsa = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
dsa.format(number);

Expected O/P: ๑๒๓.๒๒
Output received: 123.22

Why are you not using NumberFormatter as instructed in the documentation?

try new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("th").setRegion("TH").setExtension(Locale.UNICOD E_LOCALE_EXTENSION, "nu-thai").build() -- based on the question java Locale.Builder setExtension(Locale.UNICODE_LOCALE_EXTENSION (searched on this site)

@BasilBourque Even when I use NumberFormatter, I get English numbers as O/P.
